# Convert CopyFileEx to Task pattern

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, file-copying

Have been reading about async and tasks and been attempting to convert the CopyFileEx method via PInvoke to the Task pattern with progress. I am having issues with the progress part.

CopyFileEx has a callback called CopyProgressRoutine which has a parameter called lpData that takes a pointer. I thought i could use this to pass around my IProgress interface so I could report progress. However, turns out I have to use a structure, not a class. Any ideas how I can get this working, OR am I heading in the completely wrong direction with this one?

```
public class ProgressReportAsync
{
    public int PercentDone { get; set; }
    public string InfoText { get; set; }

    public void setProgress(long _progress, long _total)
    {
        PercentDone = Convert.ToInt32((_progress * 100) / _total);
        InfoText = PercentDone + "% complete."; ;
    }
}

class FileCopyAsync
{
    class UserCallbackArg
    {
        public CancellationToken ct;
        public IProgress<ProgressReportAsync> prg;

        public UserCallbackArg(CancellationToken _ct, IProgress<ProgressReportAsync> _prg)
        {
            ct = _ct;
            prg = _prg;
        }

        public UserCallbackArg() { }
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CopyFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine, Object lpData, ref bool pbCancel, CopyFileFlags dwCopyFlags);

    private delegate CopyProgressResult CopyProgressRoutine(long TotalFileSize, long TotalBytesTransferred,
        long StreamSize, long StreamBytesTransferred, uint dwStreamNumber, CopyProgressCallbackReason dwCallbackReason,
        IntPtr hSourceFile, IntPtr hDestinationFile, IntPtr lpData);

    [Flags]
    enum CopyFileFlags : uint
    {
        COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS = 0x00000001,
        COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE = 0x00000002,
        COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE = 0x00000004,
        COPY_FILE_ALLOW_DECRYPTED_DESTINATION = 0x00000008,
        COPY_FILE_COPY_SYMLINK = 0x00000800,
        COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING = 0x00001000
    }

    enum CopyProgressResult : uint
    {
        PROGRESS_CONTINUE = 0,
        PROGRESS_CANCEL = 1,
        PROGRESS_STOP = 2,
        PROGRESS_QUIET = 3
    }

    enum CopyProgressCallbackReason : uint
    {
        CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED = 0x00000000,
        CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH = 0x00000001
    }

    private static bool m_bCancel;

    private CopyProgressResult CopyProgressHandler(long total, long transferred, long streamSize, long StreamByteTrans, uint dwStreamNumber, CopyProgressCallbackReason reason, IntPtr hSourceFile, IntPtr hDestinationFile, IntPtr lpData)
    {
        switch (reason)
        {
            case CopyProgressCallbackReason.CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED:

                UserCallbackArg ucarg = (UserCallbackArg)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lpData, typeof(UserCallbackArg));

                IProgress<ProgressReportAsync> prg = ucarg.prg;
                ProgressReportAsync prgReport = new ProgressReportAsync();

                prgReport.setProgress(transferred, total);
                prg.Report(prgReport);

                if (ucarg.ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    m_bCancel = true;
                }

                return m_bCancel ? CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CANCEL : CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CONTINUE;

            default:
                return CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
        }
    }

    public FileCopyAsync() { }

    public Task DoWorkAsync(string _from, string _to, CancellationToken ct, IProgress<ProgressReportAsync> prg)
    {
        return TaskEx.Run(() =>
        {
            bool copyResult;

            if (File.Exists(_to))
            {
                //throw new Exception("File already exists: " + _to);
            }

            if (!File.Exists(_from))
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(_from);
            }

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(_from);

            m_bCancel = false;

            UserCallbackArg ucarg = new UserCallbackArg(ct, prg);
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(ucarg, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            IntPtr ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();


            if (fi.Length > (1024 * 1024 * 100))
            {
                //Greater than 100mb then no buffer flag added
                copyResult = CopyFileEx(_from, _to, new CopyProgressRoutine(CopyProgressHandler), ptr, ref m_bCancel, (CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE & CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS & CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING));
            }
            else
            {
                copyResult = CopyFileEx(_from, _to, new CopyProgressRoutine(CopyProgressHandler), ptr, ref m_bCancel, (CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE & CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS));
            }
            if (!copyResult)
            {
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                if (m_bCancel && (error == 1235))
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(error);
                    throw new Win32Exception(error);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You should make DoWorkAsync synchronous. Just wrapping a thread around a synchronous action is an anti-pattern. The caller can do that himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to move the CopyProgressHandler callback to your user arguments class. In that case you can use ucarg.CopyProgressHandler as your CopyProgressRoutine and invoke methods on the IProgress reference you stored in your user arguments class. Probably you can move the m_bCancel flag to that class too.

With this approach you are avoiding the marshalling of your data.